# Internal vs external api methods

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an API and deciding whether I should differentiate external vs internal calls.  I was thinking that I would use the same controller class for both internal and external APIs (example: ProductsController.cs (handle the product resource)) with different methods (as different parameters and different return objects, and different authorization) for internal vs external consumption.  I am thinking this might become a maintenance nightmare if I want to change api's for internal but not want to change for internal, and it not being obvious which are which.  I am thinking that maybe different controller files would be easier for maintainability, but I know they are dealing with the same resource, so I am having an internal fight of which would be the best direction.  I also realize that changing of the api would most likely force a change in internal and external apis and thus versioning will also play a role. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While they both handle the same resource they do it very differently from what you are saying so it looks like your `ProductsController` ends up doing two very different things.

To me it's quite obvious that you need to separate them.

You could put them in different `namespaces`, or even different `Areas`. If you happen to have some shared logic, you can have that in a *base class*.

Comment: yes, I am more worried about changing the interface of the api, and have it affect the external.  They are the same actual Resource, so I am having a difficulty in making it a different controller.

Comment: Yes but from my understanding you are serving the same resource in two very different ways. While in the Repository it might be the same resource, your API serves it like two different resources.

Comment: only serves a different view of the object.

Comment: Well you have asked for suggestions. This is mine :)

Comment: I have a MVC Web API hosted internally (e.g. http://myweb:123) which is only accessible from inside the network. How can I make it so people from outside can also access it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create public (external) and private (internal) folders and have a Products controller in both. They could be unrelated or share a base class.

Comment: I have a MVC Web API hosted internally (e.g. http://myweb:123) which is only accessible from inside the network. How can I make it so people from outside can also access it?